# Nvidia Drivers and Two Screens problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, 15.10, multiple-monitors

Well, I like games and most of games I have only work with OpenGL 4.0, but when I use X.Org driver it only has OpenGL 3.0; and with the Nvidia 364.19 driver (My notebook has a GeForce GT 750 M) it has the OpenGL 4.0.

[THIS IS THE MAIN POINT, IF YOU DON'T WANT TO READ WHAT IS ABOVE]

I have a TV above my notebook that I use if I want to see a movie or play with my game-pad. But both the Nvidia (364.10) driver, when I connect the HDMI and turn on the television, both screens go black and go back to normal then I have to change the "work area (I don't know how it's called) (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and then appears an image on the two screens, but it goes back to the login screen (if I have any program running it's closed), and in some cases all the extensions in Gnome Shell are turned off...

A thing that isn't so important (I think) but happens too when I use this driver is the fact that whenever I login, appears a window saying that an error has curred and if I want to report it.

Sorry but I only have one (could be)image clue...

Image of the a log in the terminal mode:
[image: Image of the a log in the terminal mode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> is a virtual terminal, VT1.

Usually you would go back to your previous X11 session by typing

> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

or

> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>

I have never had things running in the X11 display change or fail simply because I went to VT1 and back again.

But if you go to VT1, and then you are provoking some kind of error that triggers the login to re-appear, I expect it means you've corrupted that login session and things that were running are not running anymore. That makes sense.

If you cannot run <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> in quick succession and go back and forth from virtual terminal to X11 display, it may mean some configuration is broken.  Recently a customer here had an Ubuntu system where VT1 was disabled, and it simply locked the computer to try it.  I never got to the bottom of it.

Comment: Thanks to @anand mbs for editing and beautifying this comment with the key highlights.

Comment: It is always my duty @pauljohn32